# Asp.net datagrid - format meters to feet

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using asp.net 4.5, I have a gridview bound to a sqlserver table.

I have a column of type float that contains a distance value in meters.

However, I'd like to show the value to the user in feet with ft at the end.

Like: 3.28 ft

Is there an opportunity to do a complex conversion of what the user sees?

Also, if the user types in a value of "3.28 ft" I'd like to convert it into meters and store it into the database. Is this also possible?

If either of these are possible, can you point me in the general direction of how this can be done??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CellFormatting and CellParsing events to control the difference between what is shown to the user and what the actual underlying data value is. CellFormatting occurs just before the data value is shown and allows you to edit it before it is presented to the user. CellParsing occurs just after the user edits the value and allows you to convert the input value from one or more formats back to the original data type.

[MSDN on CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)
[MSDN on CellParsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing.aspx)